# SqlIntegratedChangeTrackingPolicy on Azure SQL database (table) not updating Cognitive Search index

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

I have set up my index & indexer to use `SqlIntegratedChangeTrackingPolicy`:

Data Source has `dataChangeDetectionPoligy` set:

[image]

I've enabled change detection on the database:

[image]

And on the table:

[image]

If I make a change to a column in the table, I can see it show in the changes table:

[image]

But the indexer doesn't get triggered to recognise the change. What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see. I thought the change tracker would somehow trigger the indexer to run. I have to either schedule the indexer or trigger it via the API / portal.